# Calculating whether a result falls within 2 percentage variables PHP

Tags: php, variables

I am trying to find whether a variable that I am calculating falls within a 20% range of a predefined number.

For example: predefined number is 8 (20% is 1.6) so the number would need to fall between 6.4 and 9.6.

What would be the best way to do this via PHP please?

//------------------- APOLOGIES FOUND A WORKING ANSWER

Apologies worked this out by thinking about it!

Here is the code for others:

```
// Calculating the variables and defining the top and bottom ($read = 8 for example)
$calspeed = $read * 0.2;
$topspeed = $read + $calspeed;
$btmspeed = $read - $calspeed;

// $avg is taken from a sql query drawn from database
if ($avg > $btmspeed && $avg < $topspeed){
    echo "this is an acceptable reading speed";
}else{
    echo "wrong";
}
```

Comment: Show some code, and we'll help you from there. Asking for free code is not what [SO] is for.

Comment: This assumes your value in read is a floating point variable.  If not you're going to get some screwey results.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?PHP
$predefined = <<WHATEVER>>;
$range = (float) $predefined * 0.2;
if ( $range > abs( (float)$input - (float)$predefined))) {
  //Declare Victory
}
```

This has the benefit of supporting integers and allows you to coerce the values into something similar for the more complicated data formats.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your predefined number is `$x` and the number you want to test is `$y` here you go:

```
<?php

if ($y > $x * 0.8 && $y < $x * 1.2) {
...
}
?>
```